Script doesn't get called when internally navigating
I am converting a .net site to next.js.  I don't want to rewrite all the javascript so I am just loading their main.js file in the head of the layout file using a the next.js Script component.  This file is 52,000 lines long and I don't have the time to rewrite it all in React.  Everything works well on load, but the javaScript doesn't work after internal navigation, it only works when the page refreshes.
I've tried to remove the script tag and to reappend it when the path changes, however it only partially works.  I assume some of the elements are not available in the DOM yet for events to be attached. There is a timing issue in that I need to wait for all the components to mount before appending this script, but there are 100's of possible components.
useEffect(() => {
const script = document.createElement('sc`your text`ript');
script.src = '/Casino/assets/js/main.js';
script.async = true;

return () => {
  document.body.removeChild(script);
};

}, [router.asPath]);e
Is there a way to know when all elements have finished mounting?  Is there another approach I can take with this?

You sure your code has document.createElement('sc`your text`ript');? Because if it does: problem found. If it doesn't, please [edit] your post to fix it up.

Next.js uses client-side routing for internal navigation. This means when you navigate to a different page, the entire page is not reloaded from the server. Instead, Next.js dynamically updates the content.
This given approach dynamically loads the script on each route change, ensuring your JavaScript functions are re-initialized and work correctly after internal navigation.
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
const handleRouteChange = () => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = '/Casino/assets/js/main.js';
  script.async = true;

  script.onload = () => {
    if (typeof window.initMainJs === 'function') {
      window.initMainJs();
    }
  };

  document.body.appendChild(script);

  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  };
};

router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
handleRouteChange(); // Initial load

return () => {
  router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
 };
  }, [router.events]);

return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

export default MyApp;


I believe the issue is that the mainJs script is attaching event listeners to elements, but the elements are not yet in the DOM.
What makes me think this is because if I reappend and call the script with a slight timeout, it works.  Otherwise it mostly works.  I assume it's because most of the elements are available.
